# How add user data to an already registered user

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to the database world. In my registration process a user has to give the values, which are required (e-mail and password). Now when already registered and logged in, I want to give the user the opportunity to add the not required info to his row in my database.

**EDIT2:**

Here is an updated version of the relevant part of my code. It is obviously not working, I would be beyond happy, if you could point me into the right direction once again! Thank you!!

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'database_connection.php';

$first_name = trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);    
$last_name = trim($_REQUEST['last_name']);
$URL= trim($_REQUEST['URL']);

//Get the logged in user's ID
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
//Select the logged in user
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $user_id;
//Update the user's row
$update_sql = sprintf("UPDATE users (first_name, last_name, URL) " . 
                        "VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s');",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($last_name),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($URL));
//Parameterized queries
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET (first_name, last_name, URL) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :URL) WHERE (user_id = :user_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':URL', $URL);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();


mysql_query($select_query, $update_sql, $stmt)
    or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: show_user.php?user_id=" . mysql_insert_id()); //where to redirect 
exit();
?>
```

The form, which should execute the above code but does not:

```
<body>
<!-- start register --> 
        <div id="register">
            <form name="completeProfileForm" action="/php/complete_user.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <h2>Complete your information:</h2>
                <!-- first name -->
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="name" placeholder="Enter your first name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your firstname'" />
                <!-- last name -->
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="name" placeholder="Enter your last name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your last name'" />

                <!-- website-->
                <label>Website</label>
                <input name="URL" id="URL" type="text" placeholder="Enter your website domain" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your website domain'" />

                <!-- register button -->
                <input type="submit" id="submitButton" class="button" value="Complete my profile" />
            </form>
        </div> <!-- end register -->
</body>
```

Last but not least the error message:

Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\complete_user.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\complete_user.php on line 20

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\complete_user.php on line 20

Thank you so much for all the good input!

Comment: You are missing a comma in your UPDATE statement. But what does "not required info" mean? Your code does not include, or indicate, what this might mean.

Comment: The values I define at the beginning are 'not required' information. Let's take for example facebook. You can sign up with a username and password and use the whole website just fine. But if you want to, you can add pictures, your birthdate etc. etc. That is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: that wont update............hint:  because you haven't use a function that would execute that statement

Comment: @kevinabelita It could be that the function is called in his code, but he only posted the code where he thinks the error might be.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not post that part:    mysql_query($update_sql)
  or die(mysql_error());
 
 header("Location: show_user.php?user_id=" . mysql_insert_id()); //where to redirect 
 exit(); That is how my code ends!

Comment: @KhorneHoly well its not included inside the OP's question so we really dont know. if its inside the present code, the answer below should suffice

Comment: @kampfkuchen edit your question containing the WHOLE code not just a part we can't help properly like this.

Comment: Have you tried to access the data via `$_POST['']`/`$_GET['']` instead of `Request`?

Comment: @KhorneHoly no I did not try that! I will will try that out!

Comment: @KhorneHoly Unforunately, that does not solve the problem. But I am also not getting redirected to my Header Location. Does that information help in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Updatescript should work as far as i know if you chain the text and variables together correctly.

The concatenation in `PHP` works with the dot `'.'`.

So your SQL Statement must look like

```
$update_sql = ("UPDATE `users` SET `first_name` = ".$first_name.", `last_name` = ".$last_name.", `user_type` = ".$user_type.", `URL` = ".$URL." WHERE `user_id` = ".$user_id);
```

**BUT** you shouldn't just use the input from user in your querys. See more about [SQL Injection here!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

You must escape the user input!

You can do this with certain functions, these are two of them:

```
$user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($user);
$user = htmlentities($user);
```

Also you shold use parameterized queries. This is an simple example with the first parameter of your Update Query, just add the rest of your code in the same pattern after you escaped it!:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET (firstname) VALUES (:firstname) WHERE (userid = :userid)");
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Further you are using `mysql_insert_id()` which `Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).` More Information about that in the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

But MySQL will only generate a ID if you are **INSERTING** a new User in your case, but your updating a existing one. So no ID will be returned. You need to get the ID from the User manually with a **SELECT** after the **UPDATE** and than add this ID to your redirect.

**EDIT2**

You can, and should to save traffic, put your

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET (first_name) VALUES (:first_name) WHERE (user_id = :user_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET (last_name) VALUES (:last_name) WHERE (user_id = :user_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET (URL) VALUES (:URL) WHERE (user_id = :user_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':URL', $URL);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

in a single statement

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET (first_name, last_name, URL) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :URL) WHERE (user_id = :user_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':URL', $URL);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm going through your Error messages and tell you what they mean, i think that should be enough so that you can fix them

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\complete_user.php on line 10
```

This means that your `$_Request['user_id'] doesn't find a key`user_id`. Watching your HTML, this is a bit complicated. You need to save the user_id in a [Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) when he's logging in and access it then with $_SESSION['user_id']. It would be to broad to wrote this here, but that's what you need. What you are doing now is to require the UserId from the Form, but the Form never works with the userId and the form also never sends the userId to the PHP File.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\complete_user.php on line 20
```

`$dbh` is just from the example. You never initialized this variable. You need to work with your own instance from the `MySQLi` Class. This should be done in your php file that handles your database connection. So i'm guessing that you already have this instance, you just called the wrong variable.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\complete_user.php on line 20
```

Since `$dbh` isn't a instance from `MySQLi` you obviously can't call the `prepare()` function from `MySQLi` because PHP has no clue from it. So you need to work with your own `MySQLi` instance, preferbly from your `database.php`.

Hint: The same goes with `MySQL` as you're working with that, but you should change it to `MySQLi` since `MySQL` is deprecated and will be deleted in the 5.5 Version of PHP.